# Kendo template and field data not exist

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-template

I have this sample :

```
<ul id="users"></ul>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="myTemplate">
    #if(isAdmin){#
        <li>#: name # is Admin</li>
    #}else{#
        <li>#: name # is User</li>
    #}#
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var templateContent = $("#myTemplate").html();
    var template = kendo.template(templateContent);

    //Create some dummy data
    var data = [
        { name: "John", isAdmin: false },
        { name: "Alex", isAdmin: true }
    ];

    var result = kendo.render(template, data); //render the template

    $("#users").html(result); //append the result to the page
</script>
```

I would like to know if it possible to have a data which not exists and test with a function but apparently, it doesn't work ....

```
var data = [
            { isAdmin: false },
            { isAdmin: true }
        ];
```

Do you have a idea ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: _"it doesn't work"_, what do you mean by this? Doesn't display correctly, produces errors? This [dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/ACIjoC/2) is working for me..

Comment: No it doen't work with this data for example var data = [
        { name: "John" },
        { name: "Alex", isAdmin: true }
    ];

Comment: You just need to provide some validation of the data through the template, see answer below..

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure there are no issues when using `x-kendo-template`, ensure to validate the data provided to the template.

For example if you provide:

```
var data = [
  { name: "John" }, 
  { name: "Alex", isAdmin: true } 
];
```

To the template, you can modify the `template` to check like following:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="myTemplate">
    #if(typeof(isAdmin) != "undefined" && isAdmin != null){#
      #if(isAdmin && name.length > 0){#
        <li>#: name # is Admin</li>
      #}else if(name.length > 0){#
        <li>#: name # is User</li>
      #} else {#
        <li>No name provided</li>
      #}#
    #}#
</script>
```

[Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ACIjoC/16) to demonstrate this.